# When I'm Intalling The PHP Storm and then Trying to Chaning My IP With Open-Connect VPN fetching and Issue - IP Not Changing

Tags: phpstorm, vpn, openconnect

Step:

1. Install Open Connect GUI and add the Conneconfiguration.
2. Connect the VPN(IP Changing).
3. Install the PHP Storm and Connect the VPN server but IP Not Changing.
   I checked it through the browser. What is my IP.
   Want to Change the IP but Not CHanging